# Why am I not receiving OTP on Vodapay test app when signing up?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I have access to the Vodapay test/sandbox app on both iOS and Android. When I create a new account, it asks for an OTP. However, I am not receiving an OTP on the number I signed up with. Anyone else experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sandbox/test app, you can use ‘88888’ as the OTP whenever the app requests for an OTP.